# Is every complex irreducible representation of a finite group $G$, isomorphic to a minimal left ideal in $\Bbb C [G]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, ideals

I remember reading this statement somewhere, maybe "Fulton-Harris: Representation Theory"? However I can't find a proof. I have to give a talk and I want to say "Finding irreducible representations of a finite group $G$ is as hard as finding minimal left ideals in $\Bbb C[G]$" but I want to be sure this is true.

Comment: This is [Maschke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem#Proofs) I'd say.


Given an irreducible representation $(G,V)$ take $v\in V-0$ and let $f(g)= g.v$ a surjective linear map $\Bbb{C}[G]\to V$. Then $\ker(f)$ is a subrepresentation of $\Bbb{C}[G]$ and $\Bbb{C}[G] = W\oplus \ker(f)$ with $W$ a sub-representation, your minimal left-ideal isomorphic to $V$ as $G$-module (concretely take a projection $P:\Bbb{C}[G]\to \ker(f)$, let $Q=\frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} g Pg^{-1}$ then $W=(I-Q)\Bbb{C}[G]$).

Comment: Thanks! Super clear

Comment: How can I choose $v$ in a way $f$ is surjective?

Comment: Your representation is irreducible.

Comment: Oh, $f$ is $G$-invariant so its Image it a non-cero ($v \neq 0$) subrepresentation, thus all V. Correct?

Comment: Yes. $f$ is an homomorphism of $G$-module, that is $f(g.x)=g.f(x)$.